# Group By date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT  DISTINCT AccountID,  
        FolderID,   
        EffectiveDate, 
        MAX(SUBSTRING(VersionNumber, CHARINDEX('_',VersionNumber )+1, LEN(VersionNumber))) as VersionNumber
FROM [Temp].[DocumentList] 
WHERE IsMajor = 1
AND AccountID=331  
GROUP BY EffectiveDate, VersionNumber, FolderID, AccountID
```

Data:

```
AccountID   FolderID    EffectiveDate               VersionNumber
331         4239        2014-01-01 00:00:00.000     1.0
331         4239        2014-02-01 00:00:00.000     2.0
331         4239        2014-07-01 00:00:00.000     3.0
331         4239        2015-01-01 00:00:00.000     1.0
331         4239        2015-03-01 00:00:00.000     2.0
331         4239        2016-01-01 00:00:00.000     1.0
331         4239        2016-07-01 00:00:00.000     2.0
331         4239        2016-09-01 00:00:00.000     3.0
331         4239        2016-09-01 00:00:00.000     4.0
331         4239        2016-09-01 00:00:00.000     5.0
331         4239        2017-01-01 00:00:00.000     1.0
331         4239        2017-01-01 00:00:00.000     2.0
331         4239        2017-01-01 00:00:00.000     4.0
331         4239        2017-07-01 00:00:00.000     3.0
```

I want max version Number for a single Date

Comment: You need to learn how to format your posts. However, more important here is to show what you have done to try and solve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by selecting everything you have already selected and using the `MAX()` function with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT AccountID, FolderID, EffectiveDate, MAX(VersionNumber) VersionNumber
FROM
(
    SELECT AccountID, FolderID, EffectiveDate,Substring(VersionNumber,Charindex('_',VersionNumber )+1, 
    LEN(VersionNumber))) as VersionNumber
    FROM        [Temp].[DocumentList] 
    WHERE      IsMajor =   1
               AND AccountID=331 
) t  
GROUP BY AccountID, FolderID, EffectiveDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
SELECT MAX(VersionNumber) FROM TableName WHERE EffectiveDate=@parameter
```

You're selecting the highest value of VersionNumber wherever the EffectiveDate appears. It may need a little nudging and tinkering, but that should be the mechanic of it!

[Here's a link to the MIN and MAX function!](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp)

Comment: I want the output in a table as i mentioned don't want any parameter.

Comment: In that case, you'd want to use a `GROUP BY` statement! I'd recommend looking at Rigerta's answer and at this article! https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AccountID, FolderID, EffectiveDate, VersionNumber
FROM
(
    SELECT AccountID, FolderID, EffectiveDate, VersionNumber, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EffectiveDate ORDER BY VersionNumber DESC) AS row_num
    FROM
    Temp.DocumentList
)A
WHERE row_num = 1
```

Comment: SELECT AccountID, FolderID, CONVERT(varchar(11),EffectiveDate,101) As EffectiveDate, MAX(Substring(VersionNumber,Charindex('_',VersionNumber )+1, LEN(VersionNumber))) as VersionNumber,
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(8),EffectiveDate,101),'/','') ORDER BY VersionNumber DESC) AS row_num
FROM  [Temp].[DocumentList] 
  WHERE  IsMajor    = 1
  and  AccountID=331  
  GROUP BY  EffectiveDate, VersionNumber,FolderID,AccountID    i tried it, it works but not properly.which i want

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you want.

```
select EffectiveDate,max(VersionNumber) as VersionNumber
from
(
        SELECT  DISTINCT AccountID,  
        FolderID,   
        EffectiveDate, 
        MAX(SUBSTRING(VersionNumber, CHARINDEX('_',VersionNumber )+1,      LEN(VersionNumber))) as VersionNumber
        FROM [Temp].[DocumentList] 
        WHERE IsMajor = 1
        AND AccountID=331  
        GROUP BY EffectiveDate, VersionNumber, FolderID, AccountID
) q
  group by EffectiveDate
```

Comment: AccountID FolderID EffectiveDate VersionNumber
331 4239 01/01/2014 1.0
331 4239 01/01/2015 1.0
331 4239 01/01/2016 1.0
331 4239 01/01/2017 4.0
331 4239 02/01/2014 2.0
331 4239 03/01/2015 2.0
331 4239 07/01/2014 3.0
331 4239 07/01/2016 2.0
331 4239 07/01/2017 3.0
331 4239 09/01/2016 5.0   i want this outpot max versionNo for a single date

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    SELECT  DISTINCT AccountID,  
        FolderID,   
        EffectiveDate, 
        MAX(SUBSTRING(VersionNumber, CHARINDEX('_',VersionNumber )+1, LEN(VersionNumber))) as VersionNumber
FROM [Temp].[DocumentList] 
WHERE IsMajor = 1
AND AccountID=331  
GROUP BY EffectiveDate, FolderID, AccountID
```

You want to find the max version number so don't group by that